# How can I import NetAdapter module in powershell 5.0 on Windows 7 Ox64?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I upgraded to the latest and greatest Powershell 5.0 on my Windows 7 box. I was mainly doing it to work with the Get-NetAdapter cmdlet, but it seems it is not available to me. Is this cmdlet specific to Win8/Server8 power shell 4.0 only? Do I need to load a separate module maybe?

tried command `Get-Module -ListAvailable`. No module found named NetAdapter.

Comment: [This link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/01/15/using-powershell-to-find-connected-network-adapters/) has some examples for querying network adapters with Powershell in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this cmdlet specific to Win8/Server8 power shell 4.0 only?

Yes;  The cmdlet is only aviable on **Windows Server 2012+**

[image]

Source: [Get-NetAdapter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867.aspx)